# To check if List<Map<String, String>> is empty or not

Tags: java, list, nullpointerexception, null

The answer from a library (`DBpediaLookupClient.variableBindings()`) results in

```
List<Map<String, String>>
```

I am trying to check is if the list if empty or not. 
What I have tried so far is

```
if (dbpedialookup.variableBindings() != null && !dbpedialookup.variableBindings().isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Results Present);
} else {
    System.out.println("No Results");
}
```

But, on items where the resultant List is []. Its throwing,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How do we check for `null` in such a situation?

Comment: How do you test resultant that resultant List is [] if it is throwing an Exception? I suggest you check references one after another.

Comment: The check for `variableBindings()` not returning `null` and testing `isEmpty()` only if `variableBindings()` does not return `null` looks correct. The only viable alternative is that `dbpedialookup` is `null`. Please add this check too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like the top object is null so

```
if (dbpedialookup != null && 
    dbpedialookup.variableBindings() != null &&
   !dbpedialookup.variableBindings().isEmpty()) {
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is the pattern:

```
if (myList != null && !myList.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Isn't empty");
} else {
    System.out.println("Is empty");
}
```

If you want to check variables in the list use the following:

```
if (myList != null) {
    for (Map<String, String> map : myList) {
        if (map != null) {
            //perform on map
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Optional to tidy things up:

```
if (Optional.ofNullable(dbpedialookup).map(DBpediaLookupClient::variableBindings).map(List::isEmpty).orElse(true))
    // it's empty / null
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that that's tidier than Scary Wombat's approach; but even if it is, I feel confident that this answer won't actually help the OP understand what the problem was.